# 1064 error during joining tables

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT School_info.district_id,count(School_info.no_of_class) ls 
from   School_info where     school_level IN('ls')  
JOIN
SELECT t.district_id,count(t.no_of_class) p from School_info as t     
where school_level IN('ps')
ON
( School_info.district_id = t.district_id)
```

Where is my error , i did not find it . when i ran the query above , it shows as : -

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'JOIN SELECT t.district_id,count(t.no_of_class) p from
>   School_info as t where sc' at line 2

Comment: your `where clause` had a pre-mature situation for starters

Comment: if you give me , hint to do the correction , i will be better for it .

Comment: Explain in brief about what results are you expecting from the query.

Comment: district_id     ls    and   p  as columns.

Comment: looks like count is p

Comment: if you had provided a small sampling of your data this would be mostly unnecessary speculation ya know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has a lot of syntax errors, but in any case it can be simplified as this:

```
select 
    district_id
    , sum(school_level = 'ls') ls 
    , sum(school_level = 'ps') p
from school_info 
where school_level in ('ls','ps') 
group by district_id
```

The `sum(school_level = 'p')` uses the fact that MySQL does a boolean evaluation of the expression inside the `sum()` which returns 1 if true. Summing all 1s gives the same result as counting rows.

This will give you an output like this:

```
district_id ls p
```

where `ls` and `p` are counts.

Comment: I'm afraid he is using his aliases in his `in ()`

Comment: @DrewPierce I'm not sure about that. I think `p` and `ls` are the actual levels and that the aliases used are just chosen to reflect that.

Comment: could very well be ! But he also has his count in the `in ()`. It all looks like made up sql

Comment: sorry , guys , i had mistake in my questions , i just edited it

Comment: the aliases is not in the IN  , actually